# Why is ColdFusion altering the values in my query results?

Tags: string, select, coldfusion, cfquery

This is a weird one I've never noticed before.

I am running a SELECT query in ColdFusion 8 against an iSeries/DB2 database.

Here's the query in it's simplest form:

```
<cfquery name="qMyData" datasource="#APPLICATION.DataSource#">
    SELECT  'XXX  111'
    FROM    MYLIB.MYTABLE
</cfquery>
```

The value being selected is `XXX  111` (two spaces between the two strings). The value returned by the query is `XXX 111` (it removes the second space):

```
<cfdump var="#qMyData#" />
```

returns the following query result:

```
<TABLE class=cfdump_query>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TH style="CURSOR: hand" class=query title="click to collapse" onclick=cfdump_toggleTable(this); colSpan=5>query</TH></TR>
<TR bgColor=#eeaaaa>
<TD style="CURSOR: hand" class=query title="click to collapse" onclick=cfdump_toggleRow_qry(this);>&nbsp;</TD>
<TD class=query>00001</TD>
<TR>
<TD style="CURSOR: hand" class=query title="click to collapse" onclick=cfdump_toggleRow_qry(this);>1</TD>
<TD vAlign=top>XXX 111 </TD>
```

Why is ColdFusion removing the second space? Is there a workaround to ensure that I am getting the EXACT value I'm trying to retrieve?

Comment: ColdFusion generally does not alter the data that comes from the server. Can you `<cfdump var="#Repace(qMyData.colname[1], ' ', '_', 'ALL')#">` just to cross-check?

Comment: I bet it's HTML condensing the whitespace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ColdFusion isn't removing the whitespace, it's the browser, or more directly, HTML.

If you output your values like @Tomalak said, or something like this:

```
<cfoutput query="qMyData">
#replace(qMyData.myColumn," ","&nbsp;","all")#
</cfoutput>
```

You will see that the whitespace is there.

Check this out: http://www-sul.stanford.edu/tools/tutorials/html2.0/whitespace.html

You should replace your whitespace with non-breaking spaces to avoid the collapse.

Comment: That makes sense. But, what if I want the values to break? That is, I want to display the true whitespace that's stored in the database but allow the display to break it. For instance, if I have a long paragraph, I can't simply replace every space with an `&nbsp;` or the paragraph will just be one long sentence that runs off the page.

Comment: Ahh, then I think you want the CSS `white-space:pre-wrap` property. Not sure if it's the best solution though as I've rarely used it. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

Comment: Are you sure you want to have significant space right before the </td> ? That is an interesting requirement. I would be tempted to replace it with a `<span style="background : gray">&nbsp;</span>` just so that end users would know there is a significant something there.

Comment: I'm not sure, but wouldn't a <pre> tag preserve the whitespace?

Answer (score 2):

The given answer is less than ideal, I think.

Firstly as others have touched on, the collapse of sequence of white space characters is part of the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1).

If you want to preserve whitespace you should not simply change all the spaces to &nbsp; entities - that's not what that entity is for. It's for a space that doesn't break. It's not to preserve embedded white space.

@DanBracuk gives you the most semantically correct answer: if you want to preserve these runs of space when you are rendering text in the browser, you should use <pre />. That's what it's for, and it's the correct tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Blaise that it's browser which is removing extra whitespaces in html output.
You should use `format` attribute to get your expected result:

```
<cfdump var="#qMyData#" format="text" />
```